# LAN unstable upon connection initations

Tags: networking, security

For a while now my internet has been very erratic, I've tried alot of things on the computer, and few on the router, but symptoms are as such :

-Connection drops upon site refresh -Connection drops randomly during online gaming -Connection drops randomly upon new connection (application wise)

I can't figure out why, though I have many hypothesis including packet interception (could it be ?) or something in the likes of man in the middle on my route to DNS or something.

Can any pro help me with my guess or could it be something completely out my scope ?

Furthermore, and to stay in the topic, what would be a reasonable yet possibly drastic hardware/software solution to improve stability&security ?

Thank you.

TL;DR : Net unstable - WHY ? Read post for details...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a wired connection, try another cable and port. If you are using a wireless connection try changing the wireless channel or turn off auto-channel selection on your wireless router (assuming it supports this feature). Auto-channel selection features drop the wireless connection when it attempts to find another channel and thus would cut you off. Try moving from 2.4ghz to 5ghz also. This is dependant on your device supporting it.

Chances of it being packet interception or a man in the middle attack is unlikely on a home DSL connection. If you believe it to be DNS related you can change it to either Googles 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 or OpenDNS 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220 to prove it.

As it is DSL the fault is more likely to be your line dropping out or packet loss due to a line fault. If your line is noisy/crackly that will be the cause. Make sure you have filters on all the devices in the house. Most people forget their Sky boxes and it remains unfiltered which would interfere with your DSL.

Hardware wise make sure your current one has the latest firmware or you could upgrade it. Software wise make sure your O/S is up to date including any anti-virus.

Comment: Hey I'm using LAN, not WLAN, so yeah it's wired. Tried different cable already, tried different port already (on router, can't on laptop). 

Tried varying DNS's, from google to OpenDNS, doesn't change a thing.

Connection is sometimes more stable on other computers linked to the router but they sometime have the same failure as mine. Although less often, but as it's linked to activities on computer it could be a matter of connection dropping some places.

Net surveillance is a possible problem, not sure.

Comment: Have you done a security scan and anti virus? When your connection drops or stops working have you checked the lights on your router inline with your ISP instructions? If it affects all your machines this would be the common point. Have you tried connecting your laptop on 4g via your phone or at a friend's and if so do you have the same issue?

Comment: Net surveillance is going to be very unlikely. Unless you use tor, free proxy servers, vpns or your machines are infected, the only thing between you and the Internet is your service provider. The only thing they will log is RADIUS traffic to account for usage. If your are on an unlimited plan they more than likely don't. Which leads me again back to, I think you have a line fault or broadband issue causing it and you should consider contacting your service provider if none of my advice has assisted your troubles.

Comment: I have used VPN services in the past, could someone have owned my computer/network ? I reinstalled OS's a few times, it didn't solve the problem.

Security scan, antivirus, firewalls, everything I've ran, and put to various levels of security : No difference. 

Yeah I haven't tried connecting my computer to another network because if it's hacked I prefer to contain the issue where it is now.

Comment: Also, the router is now new & the issue persists, so it's not a hardware failure on router side, maybe cable problem but that makes little sense cause the network gets disrupted upon specific actions performed on computer.

Comment: I think you may have come to your own conclusion. I would pair it with your phone as if you use android or IOS then Windows is unlikely to infect it, assuming of course its a Windows laptop. If you still have the issues then it's your laptop

Comment: As I told you the problem also happen on some other computer, I could try popping another OS than windows which I use to figure if it's OS related.

Yet, if the issue happens on other computers, why would it be my laptop specifically ?

My own conclusion is such because I cannot figure what else it could be after having tested so many things.

Comment: I see you mentioned that some other computers have the same problem as yours "mine" but less often. which is why I focused on your current one. The only way you can prove it for sure is by using your other devices on another service to see if the problem moves with it, or try a friend's laptop on yours and see if they experience the same problem.  You need to prove it to your devices or the line. You can start to eliminate then.

Comment: Well, if 2 isn't enough to prove that the problem isn't isolated... I don't know.

Comment: Ok, so going by that it has to be line related

Comment: my advice would be contact your ISP if you are concerned and get them to do all the checks.. Again if they have too.

Comment: You did mention you havent connected to another LAN. Again this would prove it 

Comment: They have done the checks & sent a new router, but it didn't solve the issue. 

So if I connect to another LAN and everything works fine, what would be the conclusion ?

Comment: That there is a WAN issue of sorts. Advanced trouble shooting from your laptop would be required. As there is a possibility of packet loss in the path.

Comment: I only have TCP IP 4 activated in the LAN properties of my connection, I tried activating/disabling various things, it didn't change anything regarding stability. Maybe I missed something though, what can I do about that ?

Comment: This will be WAN side. So you need to do some path pings, traceroutes etc. To various websites and look to see if there is a common point in the ISP network where ICMP response times increase or you start to get packet loss. You can then test against them hop IP addresses. Before and after the hop, that way you know its that hop that is causing your issue. Unfortunately alot of ISP front desk support will not go this deep. But prove it off yours first by taking the laptop elsewhere.

Comment: If I tracert when I get packet loss it's global, the whole thing fails, that's why I think it's router side.

Comment: So you see packet loss on the first hop? Have you got any output from the trace you can post in the comments. Make sure you do it with option to not DNS lookup.

Comment: Sometimes packets reach destination without issue, but when it fails it's a network failure where I don't even ping the router.